# Reboot and Select Proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

I know my question title  have many same question when I type title here, but I can't find solution for my problem, I have tried one by one not help me.

[image]

I'll tell you a little before I discovered this problem.

1. First I have problem my two partitions lost on my laptop (drive d and drive e), and tried to recover this with mini partition wizard. And here my mistake, when I change label drive, but I choose "active" and "apply" and then my laptop bluescreen - restart - and blackscreen with message "Reboot and Select Proper Boot Device or Insert Boot Media"
2. I tried using diskpart via repair cd window, and check detail disk looks like :

   > ```
   > DISKPART
   > Microsoft DiskPart version 6.1.7601
   > Copyright <c> 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
   > On computer: MININT-K1CH1RT
   > LIST DISK
   > Disk ##   Status     Size      Free     Dyn     Gpt
   > Disk 0     Online    465 GB    0 B
   > SELECT DISK 0 (confirm this is Windows 7 disk#)
   > Disk 0 is now the selected disk.
   > DETAIL DISK  
   > Disk ID : C5A496D1
   > Type : SATA
   > Status : Online
   > Path : 0
   > Target : 0
   > LUN ID : 0
   > Location Path : PCIROOT<0>#PCI<1F02>#ATA<C00T00L00>
   > Current Read-only State : No
   > Read-only : No
   > Boot Disk : No
   > Pagefile Disk : No
   > Hibernation File Disk : No
   > Crashdump Disk : No
   > Clustered Disk : No
   >
   > Volume ###      Ltr    Label          FS        Type       Size       Status       Info
   > Volume 1          C    System Rese    NTFS     Partition  100 MB      Healthy
   > Volume 2          D    WIN7           NTFS     Partition  73 GB      Healthy
   > Volume 3          E    DATA           NTFS     Partition  244 GB     Healthy
   > Volume 4          F    MASTER         NTFS     Partition  148 GB     Healthy
   > ```

Can someone tell me how do I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try make volume active through diskpart?
If not - try:

```
diskpart
select volume 2
active
```

Comment: I have tried it before make this question. Boot Disk still 'no'

Comment: After setting partition active in diskpart, what output diskpart gives? Can you show output of `detail partition` for partition, you made active with diskpart?

Comment: Sorry I forgot all output, but diskpart is active. I have fixed boot, using `bootrec /fixMBR`, `bootrec /fixBoot`, `bootrec /rebuildbcd` and last repair using disc repair windows 7. Thanks ko4evneg.